# git : I can checkout to commit but can't find on with git log or on bitbucket server

Tags: git

I have a project with lot of commits, for each build I store the commit code. now I'm trying to revert to a previous commit that I kept. the checkout works successfully (I can revert to this commit) but the commit is not visible neither on git log or on bitcuket server.

how can I make this commit visible again on bitbucket?

Comment: Try `git branch -a --contains <commit>` to find out from which branches the specific commit is reachable. It's expected to be visible on these branches on bitbucket if it has been pushed to bitbucket.

Comment: thanks it worked this way, I can see that im looking in the wrong branch